# Sequelize gets stuck connecting to heroku postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

there are tons of questions like this on SO but none of them really have the same problem.

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres DB with sequelize and **locally** it works with the DB hosted on heroku. It did also work a couple of days ago, but now it doesn't and looking at the diffs nothing changed in the way the app connects to the database.

When I deploy the app, it gets stuck trying to connect to the DB, until the web worker throws a timeout because the app does not bind to a port. This makes it hard to debug, since I don't have an error to work with.

```js
  async connect(): Promise<void> {
    const dbUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL as string

    if (!dbUrl) {
      throw new Error('Cannot connect to database, url not set!')
    }

    logger.info(`connecting to database ${dbUrl.replace(/:(\w+)@/, ':***@')}`)

    this.sequelize = new Sequelize(dbUrl, {
      dialect: 'postgres',
      protocol: 'postgres',
      logging: (sql, timing) => {
        logger.debug(`Executed SQL query '${sql}' in ${timing} ms`)
      },
      dialectOptions: {
        decimalNumbers: true,
        ssl: true
      }
    })
    
    // it gets stuck here
    await this.sequelize.authenticate({
      logging: (sql, timing) => {
        logger.debug(`authentication ${sql}, ${timing}`)
      }
    })
    logger.info('Database connection successful')

    logger.info('initializing models...')
    await this.initializeModels(this.sequelize)
    logger.info('synching database...')
    await this.sequelize.sync({
      alter: true,
      logging: (sql, timing) => {
        logger.debug(`Executed SQL query '${sql}' in ${timing} ms`)
      }
    })
  }
```

Here the log output:

```
ct 23 02:59:34 staging-monk-backend heroku/web.1 State changed from crashed to starting
Oct 23 02:59:40 staging-monk-backend heroku/web.1 Starting process with command `npm start`
Oct 23 02:59:43 staging-monk-backend app/web.1
Oct 23 02:59:43 staging-monk-backend app/web.1 > 8bit-bot-backend@1.0.0 start /app
Oct 23 02:59:43 staging-monk-backend app/web.1 > node build/main.js
Oct 23 02:59:43 staging-monk-backend app/web.1
Oct 23 02:59:44 staging-monk-backend app/web.1 2020-10-23T09:59:44.371Z [info] : NODE_ENV is production 
Oct 23 02:59:44 staging-monk-backend app/web.1 2020-10-23T09:59:44.375Z [info] : debug mode is off  
Oct 23 02:59:44 staging-monk-backend app/web.1 2020-10-23T09:59:44.375Z [info] : connecting to database postgres://rlbditxvnovvvq:***@ec2-54-246-87-132.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/dd1v94insrdacc 
Oct 23 02:59:45 staging-monk-backend app/api Build succeeded
Oct 23 03:00:40 staging-monk-backend heroku/web.1 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Oct 23 03:00:40 staging-monk-backend heroku/web.1 Stopping process with SIGKILL
Oct 23 03:00:41 staging-monk-backend heroku/web.1 Process exited with status 137
Oct 23 03:00:41 staging-monk-backend heroku/web.1 State changed from starting to crashed
```

The Procfile:

```
web:npm start
```

**Versions**

- `pg`: 7.5.0
- `sequelize`: 6.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2338) pointed me in the right direction. The problem was the `pg` package version, after upgrading to 8.4.1 everything works again.

Comment: Thanks! The issue for me only occured when using Heroku after no changes to my code. I guess they must have upgraded the postgres version.